# bootstrap3 text area too small

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a `textarea` in the following HTML code with Bootstrap3, which is too small. I gave its parent `div` `class="col-xs-6"`, and expect it to take about half of the page width. But on a 1300x768 screen in a maximized browser window, the `text` area is only about 1/8 of the screen width.

Can some help explain what's the cause of the small size and how to fix it?

Thanks

Code is below (and [js fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/o8fdvyhm/)):

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-6">
        <div class = "row">
            <textarea id="dataquery" name="data"></textarea>
        </div>
        <div class = "row">
            <button id="datasubmit" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-right"></span></button>
        </div>
        <div class = "row">
            Status: <br/>
            <span id="dataresult"> </span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-6">
        Results:
        <div class="table-responsive">
            <table id="datatable" class="table table-striped table-bordered">
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

</div>
```

Comment: At 1200 pixels, bootstrap switches to the `col-lg` propperty. Maybe you should add that one as well. You can, as you already do, add multiple classes to it, so if you add `col-lg-6`to the specific element, it should do fine. Further, your add a class row to the parent, but forget to add the full width `(col-something-something)` to the specific child element, stating how big it is. You might wanna add the class of `col-md-12 / col-xs-12 / col-lg-12` to it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use bootstrap class form-control to textarea like

`<textarea id="dataquery" name="data" class="form-control"></textarea>`

This class takes 100% width of the parent